# Function running way too slow

Tags: python

I am practicing Python with Project Euler, question 1, but the function I wrote to solve it is taking way too long.

I figure it's because the way I coded it not the actual method itself.
When I run this function with 10 or 15 iterations it spits out an answer instantly, but as soon as I jump it up to even 20, it doesn't show me anything for even minutes.
This is obviously a big problem if I need to go to 1000 iterations.

```
def pe1(n):
    counter = 1
    total = 0
    while counter < n:
        if counter%3==0:
            total=total+counter
        if counter%5==0:
            if counter%3==0:
                continue
            total=total+counter
        if counter % 25 == 0:
            print (total)
        counter=counter+1
    return (total)
```

Answer (score 6):

Because as soon as `counter` hits 15, your loop goes into an infinite `continue` - it's always going to hit the second `if` statement's case.

You need to move your `counter = counter + 1` line before the continue, or better yet, use something like `for counter in range(1,n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case if `counter` equals 15 and look at what happens where `counter%5==0` and `counter%3==0`, which will first occur at that time.

Consider also what will not happen for that value of `counter`, specifically, the line `counter=counter+1` won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid traps like this one, consider using

```
if ...
elif ...
elif ...
else ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use table-driven. Like this.

```
counter_map = {3:fun1, 5:func2, 25:fun3} # key is remainder.Of course,fun can be replaced with lambda.
```